# json_encode with object in array

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I'm trying to create a function in Wordpress that sends data with JSON through Curl to a Slack webhook. I'm more used to the way you structure arrays and objects in JavaScript, so doing this in PHP before it's being encoded to JSON is a bit confusing to me.

This is how the PHP for this encoding looks:

```
$data = json_encode(array(
     "username"=> "Email Notifier",
     "mrkdwn"=> true,
     "icon_emoji"=> ":email:",
     "text" => "*Name:* {$posted_data["your-name"]}\n*Email:* {$posted_data["your-email"]}\n*Subject:* {$posted_data["your-subject"]}\n*Message:*\n >{$posted_data["your-message"]}",
     ));

  // Finally send the data to Zapier or your other webhook endpoint
       $ch = curl_init("https://hooks.slack.com/services/Txxxxxx/Bxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // replace with your Zapier webook
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
       curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); //Optional timeout value
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //Optional timeout value
       $result = curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);

   return $result;
```

This sends the following JSON to the Slack webhook successfully:

```
{
   "username": "Email Notifier",
   "mrkdwn": true,
   "icon_emoji": ":email:",
   "text": "whatever" //generated by using PHP variables
}
```

I now want to be able to output the `text` property and additional properties within an array called `attachment`, like this:

```
{
   "username": "Email Notifier",
   "mrkdwn": true,
   "icon_emoji": ":email:",
   "text": "You have received a new message!",
   "attachment": [
      { 
         "text": "whatever", //generated by using PHP variables
         "fallback": "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
         "color": "#36a64f",
      }
   ]
}
```

But I'm not really sure how to solve this with the PHP syntax. Any ideas?

Comment: Be mindful of your double-quotes in double-quotes ... as that causes concatenation issues. You'll need to use single quotes on like `$posted_data['your-name']` instead of doubles.

Comment: `array('attachment' => array(array('text' => 'whatever', ...)))`

Comment: Read about [PHP arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). They are not difficult. Basically, PHP arrays work similar to Javascript objects handled using the array notation. [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) handles the proper encoding as JSON.

Comment: If you have a sample of desired json, say `print_r(json_decode($sample));` and see what array structure you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, like @deceze says.

```
$data = json_encode(array(
  "username"=> "Email Notifier",
  "mrkdwn"=> true,
  "icon_emoji"=> ":email:",
  "text" => "*Name:* {$posted_data["your-name"]}\n*Email:* {$posted_data["your-email"]}\n*Subject:* {$posted_data["your-subject"]}\n*Message:*\n >{$posted_data["your-message"]}",
  "attachment" => array(
    array( 
      "text" => "whatever",
      "fallback" => "Required plain-text summary of the attachment.",
      "color" => "#36a64f",
    ),
  ),
));

// Finally send the data to Zapier or your other webhook endpoint
    $ch = curl_init("https://hooks.slack.com/services/Txxxxxx/Bxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); // replace with your Zapier webook
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,5); //Optional timeout value
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //Optional timeout value
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

return $result;
```

Also take a look of this section on the PHP official documentation [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)